# Load JSON content into a meteor template

Tags: javascript, json, templates, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor application that should fulfil a datalist with some data stored in a JSON file as part of a process. However, I didn't succeed in importing its data to a template. So I was wondering how I could solve this.

I have stored the JSON file into panel/skills.json, and it looks like this basically:

```
{"skills":[
{"value":".NET Compact Framework"},
{"value":".NET Framework"},
{"value":".NET para Web"}
]}
```

And this is how the HTML file looks like:

```
<div class="required">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" list="tags">
    <datalist class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags">
    {{#each skills}}
        <option value={{value}}></option>
    {{/each}}
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Is there any way of getting the JSON file into a .js archive, and load it using helpers? Thank you :)

Comment: commented on my ans, have a look. if its works edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt try but this will work.

1. load json file using require
2. store values to [reactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html)
3. return from helper

**Example:**

```
var json = require('panel/skills.json');

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
 this.skills = new ReactiveVar(json);
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    skills: function (){
        return Template.instance().skills.get();
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to get the JSON file I needed with Template.instance().skills.get() and ReactiveVar. However when I try to iterate it, I get this following message: "Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values."

Comment: This is how I am trying to call it in the HTML:
`{{#each skill in skills}}
 <option value={{skill.value}}></option> 
 {{/each}}`

Comment: @CaikeMotta try 
`{{#each skills.skills}}
 {{this.value}}
{{/each}}`.. and more better approch use `{{#with}}`

Answer (score 0):

Use Can create a method in you Meteor.methods

```
meteor.methods({
    getSkills: function (){
        var Skills = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("parse/skills.json"));
        return Skills.skills;
    }
})
```

And now invoke this method in your template

```
Template.skills.helpers({
    skills: function (){
        Meteor.call('getSkills', function(err, result){
           return result;
        }
    }
})
```

I did not test yet, but I alread use something like these.

Comment: In my case I used Sessão.set('skills', result) in Meteor.call return. So I could return Sessão.get('skills'). Work well. You can use other variable to store result.